# Change color StackPanel, according to the data received from the Binding, in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to change the color of a StackPanel, according to the data  (1, 2, 3...) received from the Binding (value), which should I use?

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
   <Border Height="50" Width="Auto" Margin="3" Background="Black">
      <TextBlock FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" 
                 Text="{Binding valor}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
   </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by making a new variable in the class, and calling this new, in the xaml (Background="{Binding customBackground}")

```
public object customBackground
    {
    get
    {
    if (color == "1")//GREEN 
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 7, 166, 45));
        }
    if (color == "2")//RED
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 230, 5, 10));
        }
    if (color == "3")//BLUE
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 6, 102, 210));
    }
    if (color == "4")//YELLOW
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 189, 211, 3));
    }
    // Color por defecto
    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a converter:
http://www.smallandmighty.net/blog/using-value-converters-to-change-the-visibility-of-a-control

```
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:ColorConverter x:Key="ColorConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

XAML:

```
  <StackPanel Background="{Binding valor, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}"/>
```

Your converter would look something like this:

```
public class ColorConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            int Value = (int)value;

            if(Value == 1)
               return Colors.Green;
             else if(Value == 2)
               return Colors.Red;
[...]
            }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: Hello, I am trying to use this example in windows phone 8, but I get error using <Window.Resources> tag, this is used for wp8 apps?

Comment: For wp8 apps should use: <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources> instead <Window.Resources>